# Custom Post Type with Nested Taxonomy and Template Files

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, templates, template-hierarchy

I have a custom Post Type of "Portfolio" with a rewrite slug of `portfolio`. So the URL on the frontend is: `domain.com/portfolio`.

I have a custom Taxonomy of "Categories" with a rewrite slug of `portfolio/category`. So the URL on the frontend is: `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>/`

When I visit `domain.com/portfolio/` the Post Type template displays just fine.

When I visit `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>/` the Taxonomy term template displays just fine.

However, when I visit: `domain.com/portfolio/category/` the Taxonomy template doesn't work. I get a 404 error.

I even tested on core Post Type: `post` and core Taxonomy: `category`, with the posts page set to `/blog/`.

Same thing...

- `domain.com/blog/` Displays posts just fine, served from `home.php`
  template.
- `domain.com/blog/category/<term-slug>/` Displays just fine, served
  from `category.php` template.
- `domain.com/blog/category/` Displays 404 error.

An alternative route I've been taking in the past is to create a "page" for those 404 errors. So for example, I have `/blog/` already creates as a "page". Then I would create `/blog/category/` as another page, so that I wouldn't get a 404 error when the user navigated to: `domain.com/blog/category/`.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a work around to not have to create pages for those "Taxonomy Archives"?

How can I have a nested Taxonomy URL and have the `taxonomy.php` or even `archive.php` template work?

Comment: What would you *like* to happen when a user visits `domain.com/portfolio/category/`? All posts (same as `/portfolio/`)? Or a list of categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Appending Taxonomy Terms to Post Type URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161102/9579)

I believe I have come up with a temporary solution from random miscellaneous sources online.

I would love for someone to expand on my answer to make it more "bullet proof" so to speak. However, in the short run, this solution does work.

---

Hook into the current rewrite rules.

`add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'mbe_rewrite_rules_array', 100);`

Will be adding new rewrite rules to our existing rewrite rules.

```
function mbe_rewrite_rules_array($rules){
    $new_rules = mbe_get_new_rewrite_rules();
    return ($new_rules + $rules);
}
```

Add some new rewrite rules... (This area is where I think needs some improvement for sure -- I'm not savvy with rewrite rules.)

```
function mbe_get_new_rewrite_rules(){

    $post_type = 'mbe-portfolio';
    $post_type_slug = 'portfolio';

    $taxonomy = 'mbe-portfolio-categories';
    $taxonomy_slug = 'category';

    $slug = $post_type_slug.'/'.$taxonomy_slug;

    return array(
        "{$slug}/?$" => "index.php?post_type={$post_type}&taxonomy={$taxonomy}"
    );

}
```

By adding the new rewrite rule, WordPress no longer sees `domain.com/portfolio/category/` as a 404, but as a Post Type Archive instead.

Hook into the template system to display `taxonomy.php` when viewing `domain.com/portfolio/category/`

`add_filter('archive_template', 'mbe_taxonomy_template');`

```
function mbe_taxonomy_template($template){

    $templates = array();

    $post_type = 'mbe-portfolio';
    $taxonomy = 'mbe-portfolio-categories';

    if(get_query_var('post_type') == $post_type && !get_query_var('taxonomy')){
        return $template;
    }

    if(get_query_var('post_type') == $post_type && get_query_var('taxonomy') == $taxonomy){
        $templates[] = 'taxonomy.php';
    }

    $templates[] = $template;

    return locate_template($templates);

}
```

Now if you go to `domain.com/portfolio/category/` it loads `taxonomy.php` from your currently active WordPress theme directory.

So I got to thinking a bit. While `taxonomy.php` is loaded, rather than checking if we should display information about a Taxonomy or information about a term in the Taxonomy. I have decided to make a new template file called `term.php` to avoid the confusion.

Hook into the template system to display `term.php` when viewing `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>`

`add_filter('taxonomy_template', 'mbe_term_template');`

```
function mbe_term_template($template){

    $templates = array();

    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    if(property_exists($queried_object, 'term_id')){
        $templates[] = 'term.php';
    }

    $templates[] = $template;

    return locate_template($templates);

}
```

Now if you go to `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>` it loads `term.php` from your currently active WordPress theme directory.

---

### Conclusion

1. When viewing `domain.com/portfolio/` - Default archive templates are
   loaded as usual. (`archive.php`, `archive-posttype.php`, etc) from
   your currently active WordPress theme.
2. When viewing `domain.com/portfolio/category/` - The `taxonomy.php`
   template file is loaded from your currently active WordPress theme.
3. When viewing `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>` - The
   `term.php` template file is loaded from your currently active
   WordPress theme.

You can easily test to see if this works. All you need is three files in your currently active WordPress theme directory. (`archive.php` or `archive-posttype.php`, `taxonomy.php`, and `term.php`)

Put this in `archive.php` or `archive-posttype.php`

```
$current_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

echo '<p><strong>Current View:</strong> Post Type</p>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<p><strong>Current Post Type:</strong> <code>'.$current_post_type.'</code></p>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Put this in `taxonomy.php`

```
$current_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
$current_taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');

echo '<p><strong>Current View:</strong> Taxonomy</p>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<p><strong>Current Post Type:</strong> <code>'.$current_post_type.'</code></p>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<p><strong>Current View:</strong> <code>'.$current_taxonomy.'</code></p>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Put this in `term.php`

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();

echo '<p><strong>Current View:</strong> Term</p>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<p><strong>Current Term Name:</strong> <code>'.$current_term->name.'</code></p>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<p><strong>Current Taxonomy:</strong> <code>'.$current_term->taxonomy.'</code></p>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Please don't jump straight to this link. However, if you've read the entire question and accepted answer solution, and you're still confused. I've written a [blog post](https://www.michaelbrentecklund.com/wordpress-template-post-type-nested-taxonomy/) in slightly more detail, which might help you to better understand.

Answer (score 3):

That is expected and how [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) works. I know there was a track ticket raised a couple of years ago regarding this issue if to an index for archives should be introduced in core or not. (*EDIT: Found the ticket, check it out here: [Ticket #13816 There should be built-in index pages for taxonomies](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13816)*) That idea was scrapped and will never see light in core. So there will always be that gap for an archive index page in the Template Hierarchy

You can, however, create an index page for all your separate archives with the use of page templates. For instance, create a new page, add whatever you need to add to that page, and assign it a slug of `category`. Now, when you visit `domain.com/blog/category/`, you'll see the content/index page you have created.

Apart from that, there are no other solution that I know of.