# What Must to Display the "mysite.com/category" URL?

Tags: categories, templates, taxonomy, urls, template-hierarchy

I have WordPress `4.8.1` running a Twenty Seventeen child theme. When I try to open the `*mysite.com/category*` URL I get an

> OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND

message. **Is this a normal behavior?** Can be avoided this "*... can't be found*"?

Comment: What do you expect to see there? WordPress doesn't have anything to show at that URL.

Comment: @JacobPeattie And search engines knows about this? Can you suggest something constructive?

Comment: Search engines are only going to index things that are linked to somewhere. Unless you're linking to that URL, what are you worried about?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I can't understand your negative reaction. Maybe WordPress doesn't have anything to show at that URL, but for me this is a strange behavior, so I just asked if this is normal. And I am interested to know if I can do something to avoid that "... can't be found" message. You do not have to beat me for that.

Comment: But nothing can be found at that URL, so what's wrong with the message? I'm not 'beating you', I'm trying to understand what you're expectations are here because I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Can be avoided this "... can't be found"?"

**To answer your question in one line: YES**

---

> "Is this a normal behavior?"

That's because there's no template file setup to display at that segment of the URL structure.

By default, there's no template for `domain.com/category/` however, there is a template for `domain.com/category/category-name/`.

WordPress refers to: `domain.com/category/category-name/` as a "taxonomy template". But in my eyes, it should be labeled more so as a "term template". Just for the simple fact that the contents on this page are likely revolving around a term object, within the category taxonomy.

WordPress refers to `domain.com/category/` as a 404 not found, because there's no template assigned to this url segment. In my opinion, THIS is what should be referred to as the "taxonomy template".

I've asked a [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/161076/9579) and [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161102/9579) my own question on this very topic. I've also written a [blog post](https://www.michaelbrentecklund.com/wordpress-template-post-type-nested-taxonomy/) (which goes into slightly more detail) to override this template structure and functionality if you're interested. It allows you to create a specific template file for `term.php` and `taxonomy.php` so that you can have both a taxonomy archive template AND a term archive template.