# How to Rewrite Taxonomy URL to Include the Post Type as the Second Segment of the URL?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, urls, template-hierarchy

I have a custom taxonomy which is called locations which is assigned to post types which are `post` and `events`.

What I am trying to figure out is how to rewrite the URL of the terms to also include the custom post types where it will still go to the same term archive template and without breaking the pagination.

For example, the default URL of the taxonomy term that I have right now is

```
/location/europe
/location/asia
```

This is fine but I also would like to add a URL that will be for both post types the taxonomy is assigned to like:

```
/post/location/europe
/event/location/europe
```

Basically, what I am trying to figure out is support and add an additional URL segment because right now, when I try `/post-type/taxonomy/term`, it goes to a 404 page.

Is there a chance to have the URLs

```
/taxonomy/term
/post-type/taxonomy/term
```

use the same **taxonomy-term.php** template file?

Comment: [`@Jeda`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/139899/jeda) Take a look at [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161102/9579) to the question "[Custom Post Type with Nested Taxonomy and Template Files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/161076/9579)".

Comment: Hi @MichaelEcklund, thank you! This is helping me get started. The only problem I have is that I followed everything from your answer but when I try `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>/`, it goes to a 404 page even if I already resaved my permalinks and when I try to access `/category/<term-slug>/`, I get the term.php content.

Comment: I've written a relevant blog article about that question and answer, which may possibly contain updated information. It's located at the bottom of my answer. Make sure that you flush permalinks, either via code, or visit the permalinks page in the backend and re-save. Please also make sure the templating code provided is accurately followed / replicated.

Comment: I followed the guide from your blog and I have flushed the permalink settings in the backend but I am still getting a 404 for the `domain.com/portfolio/category/<term-slug>/`. Also, this approach seem to break the pagination functionality.